# How to modify URL (add GET values) after front end form submission?

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I have coded a form into a WordPress theme. Everything is working fine, except the form data will re-submit when a page is refreshed. Obviously, I need to make some change in URL in order to fix it. I am trying to add something like `?submission=success` in the URL, which I will use as a condition to display a success message or load form. How can I add this to URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
// constructing URL
$url = add_query_arg(["submission" => "success"]);

// redirection
wp_redirect($url);
exit();
```

Comment: URL is not changing.. it still shows `http://localhost/.../staff-customers-add/`. Does this have to do with format of the permalinks? Or do I have to change something in settings to enable such modifications in URL?

Comment: SOLVED! Looks like `wp_redirect()` needs to be above the header.